# Index was outside the bounds of the array exception on GridView.LoadControlState after upgrading to ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got a client with a legacy ASP.NET WebForms app that was, previously, running ASP.NET 2.0. The site needed a new feature that necessitated using a third-party component that required ASP.NET 4, so we moved his application from ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 4.0 and the move went smoothly except we're getting the following intermittent exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.LoadControlState(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadControlStateInternal(Object savedStateObj)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.maintenancetechnician_advancedsearch_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

There were some Stack Overflow questions on this, but all had to do with load balanced/multi-server environments and having this happen when a request bounced from one server with different settings than another (such as one having had some .NET SP installed and the other not).

But this is running in a single-server environment.

Moreover, this problem didn't start until the upgrade to ASP.NET 4. Searching hte ELMAH error logs reveals that this exception has happened 8 times today and not once prior to today (as far back as our logs go, at least, which is a month).

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: No code? What should be inferred from a stack trace?

Comment: @SelvaTS Please use inline code formatting only for code, not for highlighting technical words such as ASP.NET.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Ok thanks, I will follow the same. :)

Comment: It seems that somewhere in your site you have used GridView control and that is causing a problem. Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that posting code would help, but I think I may know what's happening.  We ran into a similar issue a few months ago.  It ended up being that the Gridview control had it's EnableViewState set to false.  Check that viewstate is enabled on the grid and see if that clears it up.

This site has a decent description of what happens when the viewstate is off:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1026981.aspx?ObjectDataSource+GridView+Disabled+ViewState+Major+Concurrency+Issues+possible+solution+